# remove <> automaticly in my php files

Tags: php, mysql

I call for example this element `SEND_EXTRA_ORDER_EMAILS_TO` form my database

```
SEND_EXTRA_ORDER_EMAILS_TO = test<test@test.com>
```

when I write in my php code an `echo`, `print_r` or `var_dump`

eg
`var_dump(SEND_EXTRA_ORDER_EMAILS_TO)` it write only test.
do you have an idea how to resolve this element be cause it's make to send an email

I use php 7 and mysql 7

Tk

Comment: Make it a string. If you use illegal chars in your string, use the escape (\\) char before it.

Comment: Wow, MySQL 7; what a time to be alive.

Comment: In my admin application, I tried to change by this mon service test \<test@test.fr>\ but the var_dump write  test \<test@test.fr>\ , better but not not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use htmlspecialchars() to escape the string so your browser wont treat your string as HTML.

```
$code = "<h1>Hello world</h1>";
echo htmlspecialchars($code);
// Will output <h1>Hello world</h1> without rendering the HTML in the browser
```

Comment: no doesn't work : string(0) "", the code come from the DB no inside a php file. echo SEND_EXTRA_ORDER_EMAILS_TO (in DB) = test<test@test.com> bue echo SEND_EXTRA_ORDER_EMAILS_TO write  only test

Answer (score 0):

try with that `htmlentities(EMAIL_FROM)` and works